# I want to remove the symbols from the string and reverse the string

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings

```
\\\\\\ char source[50]="12wdwq353464dlorwl35+=";
char delimis[]="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,+,=";
char *lone;
lone=strtok(source,delimis);
printf("%s \n",lone);
int i;
for(i=0;lone[i]!='\0';++i);
for(i=i-1;lone[i]>=0;i--)
printf("%c",lone[i]);
return 0;
```

\\\remove the symbols using delimis 
and reverse the string

Comment: can u spot the bugs.its working fine on some test cases not all test cases

Comment: What uis the `\\\\\\`? Show at least some test cases. Show a [mcve]. Read this: [ask]. Indent your code. [Edit] your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: It does not make sense to add multiple commas (`,`) to `delimis`. If comma is not meant to be a delimiter, remove them completely. What is the problem with your code? What output do you get, what do you expect? Or what question do you have?

Comment: calling `strtok` once will only get you the first token. That is `"wdwq"` for example. It doesn't remove all the symbol characters from the entire string. Suggest you spend some time reading the [strtok man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). Then make sure you get the "remove symbols" part working before even attempting the "reverse" part.

Comment: Note that the commas are not needed to separate the characters in a string literal as opposed to an initializer list.

Comment: @ajithnirmal Please show the input and corresponding output for working and non-working test cases. This will make the task description "remove the symbols using delimis and reverse the string" more clear. If you add enough details to the question it may get reopened.

Comment: input would be  d89%l++5r9o7W*o=16451e9H OUTPUT IS Hello World.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple commas in the delimiter list does not make sense. You probably mean

```
    char delimis[]="1234567890+=";
```

The seconf `for` loop is wrong. Instead of comparing the character value `lone[i]>=0` you probably meant to compare the index:

```
    for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--)
```

These fixes will make your program print the characters of the first token in reverse order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char source[50]="12wdwq353464dlorwl35+=";
    char delimis[]="1234567890+=";
    char *lone;
    lone=strtok(source,delimis);
    printf("%s \n",lone);
    int i;
    for(i=0;lone[i]!='\0';++i);
    for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--)
        printf("%c",lone[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
wdwq
qwdw
```

If you want to reverse all tokens, you can add a loop

```
    lone=strtok(source,delimis);
    while(lone != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n",lone);
        int i;
        for(i=0;lone[i]!='\0';++i);
        for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%c",lone[i]);
        printf("\n");
        lone = strtok(NULL, delimis);
    }
```

This will print

```
wdwq
qwdw
dlorwl
lwrold
```

Comment: thank you.but i want to print all strings not wdw && qdlorwl.,input would be  d89%l++5r9o7W*o=16451e9H OUTPUT IS Hello World

Comment: @ajithnirmal Please write the input and expected output **in your question**. I guess the input in your comment should contain `l` (lower case L) instead of 1` (number one) and there should be a space (between Hello and world) in the input. With this example you would have to add more characters to the delimiters string. The the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812247/10622916) by Vlad from Moscow might do what you need, but there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtok` is not useful to remove symbols from a string because it splits a string into sub-strings by the delimiters. You have to write your own function that does the task.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * remove_if( char *s, const char *delim )
{
    char *src = s, *dsn = s;

    do
    {
        if ( *src == '\0' || strchr( delim, *src ) == NULL )
        {
            if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
            ++dsn;
        }
    } while ( *src++ );

    return s;
}

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char source[50]="12wdwq353464dlorwl35+=";
    const char *delim = "1234567890+="; 

    puts( reverse( remove_if( source, delim ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
lwroldqwdw
```